# What stat does this number represent?

Tags: cat-quest

I've assumed the yellow sword number is melee attack, and the purple swirl is magic attack, but what is the third number for?

I've highlighted it in the screenshot.

[image: My Cat Quest hero]

Comment: The 16 is the purple number.  84 health, 18 melee, 16 purple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a badly designed interface. The numbers belong with the symbols to the left  (despite being nearer to the number to their right.

The circled number is your magic. In the screenshot you have 84 health, 18 melee, and 16 magic.